Energy Extraction from an Infinitely Large Plane of Charge and Its Implications on Energy Conservation
Consider the following scenario: if I introduce a positive point charge from infinity perpendicularly towards the electric field of an infinite plane of positive charge and release it close to the plane, of course the charge will gain kinetic energy due to the repulsive force from the plane.
If I were to repeat this process, bringing in multiple positive charges and accelerating them away from the plane, it seems I could continually extract kinetic energy from this system. This leads me to wonder: would this setup function as a perpetual motion machine, allowing for the continuous acceleration of charges without any external energy input?
Or does the principle of energy conservation impose restrictions on this scenario? Specifically, is there a limit to the amount of energy I could extract in this manner, and if so, what are the underlying reasons for this limitation?
I appreciate any insights you can provide!
PS: I think that the positive point charges I accelerate will eventually accumulate somewhere, and after some time, they might cancel out the electric field due to the infinite plane of charge.

Can I extract infinite energy from lifting a box up and letting it fall over and over again?

@CharlesHudgins But if you bring a positive point charge over an equipotential surface quasi-statically, it will not require any energy. That’s the point I was trying to make.
P.S.: Are you implying that I would need to expend energy to return the point charge, which has been repelled, to its original position to repeat the process?

I see. I interpreted "perpendicularly" incorrectly in the OP. In that case, the moving of the particles is a red herring. The field extends over to where you moved them from. They would acquire kinetic energy just the same if released from there. So why not just release them there?

@Peterswift  Regarding your last comment,  no work is required to move charge along an equipotential surface, which is a plane parallel to the charged infinite plane, but then also there is no increase in electrical potential energy that can be converted to kinetic energy when the charge is released. So what’s your point here?

@Peterswift are you going to answer my question? Because it goes to the heart of your post. When you say “ perpendicularly towards the electric field of an infinite plane” is it perpendicular to the plane of infinite charge or perpendicular to the electric field? Because if it’s perpendicular to the field you aren’t doing anything. You’re doing no work and just releasing a charge that is somehow already being “held” there. If it’s perpendicular to the plane you’re doing work that winds up adding Potential energy to the charge-plane system. Which is it?

I am very sorry, @BobD, for not noticing it earlier. I was in my hometown taking a break. I regret that I didn’t see it sooner.

@BobD The point charge is brought in perpendicular to the electric field very slowly. I understand that, no matter how slowly I bring the charge in perpendicular to the field, it will still gain some non-zero, appreciable kinetic energy.

I’m sorry again for the delayed response, @BobD.

I don’t think of potential energy as a 'real' form of energy. Instead, I see it as an alternative way to represent the work done by the electric field when moving a charge quasi-statically. Am I right in imagining it this way?

@BobD I think I have found the answer. I mentioned earlier in the comments, 'no matter how slowly I bring the charge in perpendicular to the field, it will still gain some non-zero, appreciable kinetic energy,' and that is where I will do work and give energy to that point charge?

@Peter swift potential energy is real and moving charge perpendicular to the field has nothing to do with moving closer to or farther from the charged plane or extracting energy from the electric field.


This leads me to wonder: would this setup function as a perpetual
motion machine, allowing for the continuous acceleration of charges
without any external energy input?

No.
The external energy input is the positive work you do to move the positive charge from some specified distance away from the plate to the plate against the repulsive force between them, since your force is in the same direction as the displacement of the charge. (Although you said to bring the charge from infinity, that would take an infinite amount of work since the electric field for an infinite sheet of charge
is constant).
At the same time you do positive work the electric field between the plate and the charge does an equal amount of negative work since its force (directed towards the charge) is in the opposite direction to the displacement of the charge. In doing negative work the electric field takes the energy you supplied to the charge and stores it as electrical potential energy in the field of the charge/plate system.
Then when you release the charge the field does positive work accelerating the charge giving it kinetic energy at the expense of electrical potential energy it gained.
The overall net effect is the energy you transferred to the charge becomes the kinetic energy of the charge and energy is conserved.
Hope this helps.

You cannot extract any energy in this manner, and you cannot build a perfectly-efficient system in this manner.
Suppose you have an infinite plane of charge and want to extract energy through the kinetic energy of small positive charges brought near it. You bring a small positive charge towards the plane from infinity - this requires adding an energy $E$ to the charge in order to give it potential energy in the form of proximity to the plane. To show this: at rest and at infinity, the particle has zero potential energy, and it has nonzero potential energy when near the plane, so there must be energy spent in bringing the charge close.
You release the charge. By energy conservation (or by the kinematics of the electric field if you prefer, or if you don’t trust energy conservation for some reason),  it cannot gain more kinetic energy than $E$ since, at rest with potential energy $E$, that’s exactly how much energy it has to work with. To show this: near the plane at rest, it has nonzero potential energy, and at infinity, it has zero potential energy, so that energy must be exactly converted into kinetic energy.
The resultant kinetic energy you can extract, spending $E$ to add potential energy to bring it close from infinity and then releasing it to infinity to gain $E$ in kinetic energy, is $\mathrm{d}E=E-E=0$. Energy is conserved; you cannot gain energy from this process and if you try you will certainly lose some energy in inefficiencies.
Of course, thermodynamics would have told you that from the beginning: you cannot win (by generating energy) and you cannot break even (without perfect efficiency).

Isn’t the kinetic energy acquired by the  charge when you release it equal to the energy you supplied the charge when you did work bringing it from infinity to the plate?

Yes, that is my point.

Sorry my comment was meant for the OP

But if the sheet is itself infinite, why would be consider the potential to be zero at infinity? Maybe we should we have to set 0 potential at some arbitrarily chosen point at finite distance from sheet.

That wouldn’t make sense; then the potential would be negative outside that radius. It is always the case that potential is 0 at infinite distance. Try integrating $\frac{1}\infty$ over any surface, finite or infinite.

@Proscionexium I think that you are right. For the relationship between the potential and the E field to hold, I believe that the E field has to decay as either $1/r$ or $1/r^2$ or faster. That won't happen for an infinite plane. It doesn't change the gist of controlgroup's answer, but I do think that detail is a bit tricky. I think that technically you need to assume a finite distance, calculate the work, and then take the limit as the distance increases to infinity.

@Dale Yeah. I thought the case is similar to potential due to charged infinite wire where clearly the potential is not 0 at $\infty$.


… would this setup function as a perpetual motion machine, allowing for the continuous acceleration of charges without any external energy input?

Yes. Note, that equipotential surfaces now stretch to infinity, so instead of  using a single infinity, we must assign  potentials to different points of infinity, and specify from which point of infinity we take the charge.   If we take as zero (arbitrarily) the potential of the charged plane, then there would be points at infinity with every possible value of the electrostatic potential less or equal to zero. So there are “points at infinity with $\varphi=0\,$”, “points at infinity with $\varphi=-1\,\text{V}$”, “points at infinity with $\varphi=-3.7\,\text{V}$”, etc.
OP's setup of moving charge “from infinity perpendicularly towards the electric field” means that we take the charge from some point at infinity with $\varphi=0\,$ move it along the equipotential surface  $\varphi=0\,$ and then release it. The charge would be moving along the electric field line toward  points at infinity with $\varphi=-\infty,$ gaining kinetic energy with time. Note, that since the charge's velocity is bounded, the energy gained remains always finite but growing with time.

Or does the principle of energy conservation impose restrictions on this scenario?

No restrictions. At the start, we have an infinite potential energy (because an infinite volume of space is filled with electric field of constant strength) and we convert part of that energy into kinetic energy of moving charge. But at any subsequent moment in time we would still have infinite potential energy left plus we gained some finite kinetic energy of the charge (or charges if we repeat the process with further charges). Or, formally, $$ \infty + E = \infty ,$$ for any finite constant $E$. Conceptually, this is no different than Hilbert's Grand Hotel except here we have energy gained rather than hotel rooms.

Specifically, is there a limit to the amount of energy I could extract in this manner, and if so, what are the underlying reasons for this limitation?

Infinity will never run out, so as long as we remain within our infinite charged plane setup, we can extract unlimited energy. Though, the actual values for the charge, its mass, electric field energy density, speed of light etc. can impose certain limits on power and efficiency of energy conversion.
The only meaningful limits can appear if we go from infinite system to finite. Then, the reservoir of energy would be finite and the energy that could be extracted from such system would be bounded by the capacity of that reservoir.
For example, we can consider instead of an infinite plane a flat conducting circular plate of a finite, but large radius $R$, charged so that the total charge is $Q$. The most obvious difference from infinite case is that the plate does not stretch to infinity, so there is no charge that could be taken from infinity and moved to the plate without doing any work. Infinity here is once again an equipotential surface, so amount of energy gained from charge accelerating away from such plate would be equal to work needed to first move the charge from infinity to the plate (ignoring losses). Alternatively, if we want to extract the energy from the system we can use part $\delta q$ of already present charge of the plate. Then the kinetic energy gained by  that charge would be at the expense of decreasing potential energy due to decrease of the remaining charge of the plate:
$$ W(Q)=W(Q-\delta q)+E_\text{kin},$$
(again ignoring losses). Here, conservation of energy takes familiar forms and no perpetual motion occurs but a usual conversion between different forms of energy.
